# compareTo and Strings using a Scanner

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, comparable

I am implementing a form of leftist min heap, which stores arbitrary words by length. So, I have written a wrapper class for Scanner, and changed the compareTo, like so

```
public class ScannerWrapper implements Comparable<String>

//a Scanner, sc and a String, current
public int compareTo(String str){
    if(current.length() > str.length()) return -1;
    if(current.length() > str.length()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

where current = sc.next() and is not the \n character.

in this case, if I have ScannerWrapper.next() > foo , where foo is an arbitrary string of length > ScannerWrapper.next();
will it use the compareTo(String) that I have written, returning false, or will it do some other random thing?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation seems muddled. Let my try to clarify - `String n = ScannerWrapper.next() and n.length() > foo.length()

Comment: I can't really understand your question too well, but both of your `if` statement conditions are the same...

Comment: Did you mean to use a `<` in the second comparison in the compareTo method?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the format of the code, assume it is correct as I never use exact transcripts of my code.

The second if statement is supposed to be <.

I'm asking whether or not the length of a given string length ( i < n ) given ( n > i ) will return -1 and i will be the head of a leftist min-heap

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question several times I think I understand what you're asking now. If you're trying to compare two instances of class `ScannerWrapper` with the comparison operators, then no, it's not going to work.

You can't overload operators in Java (you can in C++), therefore in order to compare instances of `ScannerWrapper` with each other you're going to have to call the `compareTo()` method.

Also, both of your `if` statement conditions are the same, so you might want to fix that up.

Comment: I never use exact transcripts of my code on here, I try to make them as general as possible. As is the case, missights like the if statements are possible, thank you for noticing.

So, I should be comparing two instances of the class ScannerWrapper?  Say I have a string length N that is the next word in the stream, and a string length i < N in my min-heap. Therefore, i should be position 0 on the min-heap, and N should be 2, and so-on. Is this how I would implement?

Comment: @SamP: You can compare a `ScannerWrapper` and a `String` or two `ScannerWrapper`s, it's up to you and how you code your overloaded `compareTo()` methods. You would use `compareTo()` to determine where in the min-heap a current value should go, but I'm guessing your heap would store either `String`s or `ScannerWrapper`s so I'd probably expect two of the same type of objects being compared to each other.

Comment: The min-heap would store strings, so perhaps I should write a class that wraps up a string and have a seperate scanner?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your question - so you might consider rephrasing it.  Here's a shot in the dark :

```
 public class ScannerWrapper implements Comparable<ScannerWrapper>

    //your wrapper has a handle to the scanned data.   Presumably it's
    //initialized on construction, which is omitted here
    private final String scannedData;        

    public String getScannedData() { 
        return this.scannedData;
    }

    public int compareTo(ScannerWrapper other) {
        //if this scannedData is longer than the other, return 1
        if(this.str.length() > other.getStr().length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if(this.scannedData.length() < other.getScannedData().length()) {
        //if the other scannedData is longer return -1   
            return -1;
        }
        //if they are equal return 0
        return 0;
    }

 }
```